# Graphics and Wireless Driver Problems on Crunchbang

Tags: drivers, crunchbang

I started using Crunchbang. However, I still have problems with graphics card and wireless drivers. My graphics card is **ATI Radeon HD 7670M** and notebook model is **Acer Aspire V3-551G**. I have downloaded the graphics card driver from this link: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64 . When I install it and reboot my PC, it doesn't start anymore and I have to reinstall Crunchbang again. My **lspci** output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: I think there is no problem with the wireless driver, but it does not scan networks.